# Firefox 57 not supporting MJPEG

Tags: firefox, mjpeg

I'm using MJPEG to easily stream data from my dev mobile phone to my browser. The app I'm using is [ScreenStream](https://github.com/dkrivoruchko/ScreenStream)

Using Firefox 57 I get an error that MJPEG is not supported by the browser. Opening the same site in Edge is working.

Why have Mozilla remove MJPEG support? Is there any way to enable it back?

TA

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem.
Seems Firefox 57 Can't Support MJPEG in this way that show on Firefox.
You can use Direct link for MJPEG file by doing this.

- Open Stream address (Ex: *192.168.1.3:8080*)
- Open Firefox Console
- Go to Inspector tab
- Find mJPEGimage link
- Open link in new tab , Now you can see stream updates

You can also save MJPEG video using *Control+S*